# Display variables/methods of a class in RCP plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse RCP plugin where one of the functionalities is to display all the variables and methods in certain classes for the user to see.

Currently I have implemented this using a File Walker which walks a file structure, when it finds a .class file it loads the class using the ClassLoader API so I can then reflect upon the class to get the declared fields and methods etc then display them.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to use the built in Eclipse Outline view as a part in my Plugin? By that I mean is it an element that can be instantiated and positioned within my plugin?

Also I will be adding a small Java editing area to my plugin at some point, so instead of creating one myself would it again be possible to make an instance of the  Elcipse' editing area and have it in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of recreating the Eclipse Java editor, why don't you just open up an editor view with the Java class you're interested in?

This would be similar to what Eclipse does with the source code for class files that you're using.

```
IFile fileToBeOpened = ...;
IEditorInput editorInput = new FileEditorInput(fileToBeOpened);
IWorkbenchWindow window=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
page.openEditor(editorInput, "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gilbert. It's an idea I may try but I was hoping to have an area inside a Part of the application because my aim is for the user to populate it by clicking on other components in the Part. Sort of like you click a button and it fills in a block of code for you.

If that isn't possible is it possible to open an editor view with another view attached which I can populate with strings?